# C++ temporaries and constructors

Tags: c++

Why do some compilers complain about taking an address of a temporary from a constructor and some dont?

For example:

```
WriteLine(&String8("Exception"));
```

I'm assuming the complaining compiler is not storing that address on the stack and it will blow up if I ignore the warning.  Is there a way to get that to work in one line?  Is the best/only way a static method on the class that returns an address?  Hmm I don't think a static method on the String8 class that returns a pointer would work since it would save the String8 class to a register and then eat it in WriteLine()

Comment: Why not have `WriteLine` take it by const reference?

Comment: How about `WriteLine(new String8("Exception"));`

Comment: @RayShih: How about no?  Instant memory leak, unless WriteLine calls delete on the pointer, which is certainly not something I'd expect a function called WriteLine to do.

Comment: Because that address might be invalid because the temporary might get destroyed. Best to take by constant reference or copy by value

Comment: So it should be
`String8 *str = new String8("Exception");
WriteLine(str);
delete str; // when it won't be used anymore`

Comment: Does WriteLine(const String8* value) force the String8 to save to the stack? Unfortunately I can't test it right now because it works without the const in visual studio C++

Comment: Which compiler does that code compile in? It certainly looks invalid.

Comment: @RyanBrown, A const reference will cause the temporary to live until the end of the full expression and keep nice syntax. I'm personally for `WriteLine("Exception"_s8)`, but `WriteLine(String8("Exception"))` works too.

Comment: @RayShih: You could do that, but it's rather pointless, and not safe if WriteLine throws an exception.  When you could just do this: `String8 str("Exception"); WriteLine(&str);` -- But the OP's purpose is to do it in one line, which, in my opinion, is a silly, pointless requirement.

Comment: @Pubby: Why is it invalid?

Comment: Thanks!  Although it really should work without the const guarantee, that might come back to haunt me sometime.

Comment: @AlokSave Can't take address of rvalues, which is what that temporary is.

Comment: It's important that it works in one line because it'll be used a LOT.  Yeah it's invalid if the compiler leaves it as temporaries but why wouldn't it save it to the stack if it sees I'm taking the address of it?

Comment: @Pubby: MSVC allows taking address of a temporary through an extension and the temporary is guaranteed to be alive till the function body ends(§12.2/3).So I don't think it is a problem. The warning in this case is a red herring.

Comment: Hey Microsoft did something right in C++, even if it is non-standard...  Also the warning isn't in VS2010, it's on a different compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example code you give,

```
WriteLine(&String8("Exception"));
```

is **invalid** as standard C++, unless the `String8` type defines a custom address operator.

---

You ask,

> “Why do some compilers complain about taking an address of a temporary from a constructor and some dont?”

Some compilers complain, because the C++ standard says you can't use the built-in address operator to take the address of a temporary:

> **C++11 §5.3.1/3**:
>   “The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand. The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*.”

Some compilers, such as Visual C++, don't complain, because they offer the ability to take the address as a **language extension**.

---

Note that a user defined type can define a custom address operator. Thus, in your case it *depends on the `String8` type*. As well as on the compiler.

---

You further ask,

> “Is there a way to get that to work in one line?”

Yes you *can* define an address operator. But it's not a good idea. First of all it only creates problems with standard library etc., and secondly, the need for that is very rare.

I can only remember one case where I seriously considered such a solution, namely for passing a COM smart pointer as out-argument. Instead of defining an address operator I defined a named method. It's much more clear and doesn't interfere with other things.

Comment: Ok so by having a custom address operator does that mean that exact line will work without the const?

Comment: @Ryan: yes, but don't do that. Instead change or create a wrapper for `WriteLine`. whatever that is.

Comment: Well the const is kind of a pain and prevents me from changing the string even if it's going to be thrown away.  Obviously you don't want WriteLine messing with the string but there are probably cases where you would want to do that.  If I can make the compiler always copy the constructor result to the stack that would be nice.  I can't think of a case where I would want the constructor result to be a temporary, can you guys?

Comment: @RyanBrown: If you want to modify the parameter without the changes being visible to the caller, take the object by value.

Comment: I guess I'd just like it to work without the const.  When the WriteLine function is already expecting a ObserveOnlyString* its kind of redundant

Answer (score 2):

The code is perfectly valid(*on MSVC*). And you can ignore the warning as red herring.

There are two issues to consider:

1. Taking the address of an temporary(*a.k.a: rvalue*), which is not allowed as per the standard &
2. Lifetime of the temporary who's address is taken.

**Counter Issue 1:**
MSVC allows you to take the address of an temporary through an extension. So taking address of the temporary shall and will compile atleast in your case(courtesy MSVC).

**Counter Issue 2:**
Further the temporary `String8("Exception")` is guaranteed to live at least until the expression ends. Note that the expressions ends just after the return from `WriteLine()`, to be precise `;`(*the semicolon at the end of call*). So it is perfectly valid. In this case you can consider the warning as an red herring.

**C++03 Standard §12.2/3:**

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.