# C++ override address operator

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I'd like to be able to do this in C++ standard compilers:

```
void DoSomething(Object* object) { }

DoSomething(&Object())
```

With the default address operator, it'll save that constructed object to a register and then overwrite it in DoSomething()... Would be really nice to do this in one line for all objects (except base types where you can't override them).

So here's what I have:

```
class Object
{
    public:
        Object* operator&(Object object) { return &object; }
};
```

Which will obviously just be a recurring loop without being able to specify I want the basic & operator, not the overriden one.  It's also not being called when I call DoSomething(&Object()).  Is this possible?  It would make initializing complex types WAY easier so it's kind of important.

Comment: That would be an atrocious thing to do! Why would it make anything easier?

Comment: Wouldn't that return an address to a temporary? Sehr bad.

Comment: Yeah I guess it wouldn't change anything, still going to be a temporary.  Oh well I guess initializing a complex object structure on the stack is going to be painful then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this in C++11:

```
class Object
{
    public:
};

Object* operator&(Object&& object) { return std::addressof(object); }
Object const* operator&(Object const&& object) { return std::addressof(object); }
```

---

All objects:

```
template<typename T>
T* operator&(T&& x) {
    return std::addressof(x);
}
```

---

Please don't do this though. People will hate you for it.

Comment: @K-ballo Fixed I suppose. Const rvalues references make me squeamish.

Comment: What I really want to do is force & to save a register value to the stack if it's being passed to a function.  Doesn't sound like it's possible

Answer (score 0):

One wouldn't normally do that in *C++*. There are ways to do it, but is just asking for trouble. Instead, a *C++* solution would do:

```
void DoSomething( Object const& object ){ ... }
```

But perhaps you would need to be able to operate on *non-const* objects as well. In that case, you would do:

```
void DoSomething( Object& object ){ ... } // operate on an lvalue, object with a name
void DoSomething( Object&& object ){ ... } // operate on an rvalue, either temporary or moved object
```

The solution would greatly differ based on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Apparently, he finds typing "const" just too much of a hassle.  See his last comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14169973/440119).

Comment: Well it's redundant and prevents situations where you would want to change it.  No I'm not going to force everyone to add 'const' if it's avoidable.

Comment: @Ryan Brown: You seem determined to go against the language, even when the language already has a construct to catch and modify temporaries... I'd say you just picked the wrong language

Comment: @RyanBrown: *"prevents situations where you would want to change it"* -- Well, obviously.  If you want to change it, then you don't want const.  Did you read my last comment on the answer in the other question though?  If you want to modify the object without the changes being visible to the caller, take the object by value.  No const.  Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: Well I want to get as close to OO as I can get in C++ while not being a giant pain in the butt, don't have the time to write a compiler right now.

Comment: There's times where you would want to pass by reference and be able to modify the object

Comment: @Ryan Brown: If you want _OO_ then you will need `new` there... Use `new Object(...)` instead of `&Object(...)`. You should take the time to learn the language; or if you don't have it, change to a language you already now...

Comment: new is heap memory, what about times where you want to work with objects on the stack?

Comment: @Ryan Brown: You can already take the address of objects on the stack, so no problem there... `&object` where `object` is of _automatic or static storage_ would work just fine

Comment: *"There's times where you would want to pass by reference and be able to modify the object"* -- Then you don't use const.  What's the problem?  If you are talking about passing temporaries, and are worried about the cost of copying, then stop worrying.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

Comment: Sure but you can't inline it like DoSomething(&Object()).  If it's not fixable it's not fixable, I'll just have to use const all over for string functions like WriteLine(&String8("Exception"));  Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: @RyanBrown: I wish you would make a post that details why you apparently think neither one of these signatures is appropriate for your `WriteLine` function: `void WriteLine(String8)`, nor this: `void WriteLine(const String8 &)` -- Either one of those would allow you to write the call as a single statement: `WriteLine(String8("Exception"));` -- It's frustrating that you haven't even called into question the appropriateness of the signature `WriteLine(String8*)`

Comment: it's void WriteLine(ObserveOnlyString* string), and which will now get const too

Comment: @Ryan Brown: LOL! _Observe Only_ as in `const`?

Comment: It's a seperate type.  Turns that const business into proper OO for when you want to mix and match access modifiers.  Much more flexible for collections and such too.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler does NOT save that return value from the constructor to the stack, fyi.  Instead it just doesn't tell you and blows up at run time if you change it inside the function.

Comment: @Ryan Brown: Constructors do not have a return value, so that's just plain wrong like everything else you have been saying... seriously, consider a different language

Comment: Seriously, consider not being such a C++ snob

Comment: @Ryan Brown: Just trying to help you avoid the pain from your own errors. Errors that others already had, even microsoft (GDI+ does something similar to what you want)... But go ahead, go against the language and then blame it for not being some other language...